# Trying to get property of non-object from another controller Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5

I don't think this is a typical non-object error, but hopefully someone with more knowledge than me can figure it out.

I have the following Controller:

```
class MangopayController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @var \MangoPay\MangoPayApi
     */
    private $mangopay;

    public function __construct(MangoPayApi $mangopay)
    {
        $this->mangopay = $mangopay;
    }

    /**
     *  Add a user to mangopay. This should be done for every new user
     *
     * @return True if successful
     */

    public function addUserToMangopay($user_id)
    {
        // get the admin user object
        $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->first();
        // set fields for mangopay
        $newMangopayUser = new UserNatural();
        $newMangopayUser->Tag = $user->role;
        $newMangopayUser->FirstName = $user->first_name;
        $newMangopayUser->LastName = $user->last_name;
        $newMangopayUser->Birthday = $user->birthday;
        $newMangopayUser->Nationality = $user->nationality;
        $newMangopayUser->CountryOfResidence = $user->country_of_residence;
        $newMangopayUser->Email = $user->email;
        // add user to mango pay, should return user object if successful
        $result = $this->mangopay->Users->Create($newMangopayUser); // <-- this line is causing issues
        if (is_object($result)) {
            $user->mangopay_id = $result->Id;
            $user->save();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The above works fine if I run it using a route like this:

```
Route::get('/add-user-to-mangopay/{user_id}', [ 'as' => 'user_id', 'uses' => 'MangopayController@addUserToMangopay']);
```

But, if I try and run this from my RegisterController which looks like this:

```
class RegisterController extends MangopayController
{
    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        $result = $this->addUserToMangopay($user->id);

        if ($this->addUserToMangopay($user->id)) {
            return $this->registered($request, $user)
                ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
        } else {
            return $this->registered($request, $user) ?: redirect($this->redirectPath()->with('alert-danger', 'There was a problem creating your account'));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get the error "Trying to get property of non-object" from the MangopayController line:

```
    $result = $this->mangopay->Users->Create($newMangopayUser);
```

I have tried various iterations of the code with no success.

What is really confusing is that I have checked the object that the error is referring to $newMangopayUser with dd(); and as far as I can see it is an object, so it should work...!

dd($newMangopayUser);

```
UserNatural {#227 ▼
+FirstName: "10"
+LastName: "10"
+Address: null
+Birthday: 1483228800
+Nationality: "GB"
+CountryOfResidence: "GB"
+Occupation: null
+IncomeRange: null
+ProofOfIdentity: null
+ProofOfAddress: null
+PersonType: "NATURAL"
+Email: "ten@e.co.uk"
+KYCLevel: null
+Id: null
+Tag: "customer"
+CreationDate: null
}
```

Anyone able to help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your parent constructor `MangopayController` is not called [implicitly](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) (that's PHP default behaviour). This means that `$mangopay` won't be injected and therefore it will be `null`.

This means that in expression `$this->mangopay->Users->Create($newMangopayUser);` you are accessing `->Users` on `null`.

So it's not `$newMangoPayUser` what is actually `null`.

Try edit your `RegisterController` as follows:

```
class RegisterController extends MangopayController
{
  ...
  public function __construct(MangoPayApi $mangopay)
  {
    // call parent constructor explicitly
    parent::__construct($mangopay);
    ...
  }
...
}
```

Moreover, in this part of code you are calling `addUserToMangopay()` twice, instead of checking `$result` (which is unnecessary, but not a big deal).

```
 $result = $this->addUserToMangopay($user->id);

        if ($this->addUserToMangopay($user->id)) {
         ...
        }
 ...
 }
```

Comment: OK great, thanks for this, I had a feeling it would be some sort of scope error like this. Also 1) I think you mean parent::__construct($mangopay), right? 2) the code at the bottom is doubled up because I copied and pasted when I was playing with code to try and fix - I am aware of this :D Thanks again